# Using SQL Server Database::: Attaching after installation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My question is if user needs to attach the databases to the instance of server manually before being able to use the application?
I have added the mdf file to my Setup project.  It installs and copies the file to application folder.  I donot know if the file needs to be attached or there is a way that application could do it automatically (attach to MyComputer\SQLExpress)

Thanks

Comment: Read this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms247257.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx

Comment: I have gone through them.  Just clear my concept, if the database is provide with the application, does user need to attach that to the server instance manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your script already copies the files to the destination folder, you can use the sp_attach_db procedure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877(v=sql.100).aspx) or even the CREATE DATABASE command with FOR ATTACH informing the file names.

Comment: Tried this link  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877(v=sql.100).aspx) bu Microsoft says donot use it any more.  Could you explain futher about CREATE DATABASE command with FOR ATTACH informing the file names.

Comment: just  inform the existing files names when you "create" a database with the FOR ATTACH statment:


CREATE DATABASE DBNAME
ON PRIMARY (FILENAME = 'c:\DBNAME.mdf')
FOR ATTACH
GO


of course, you have to respect all restrictions of the command (read them on the link I sent you)